# Flex: Children components disapear when SkinnableContainer is skinned

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex

I have a few Skinnable Containers that have children components, such as an image component or a button bar etc. It seems that when I add the skin, the Skinnable container looks great, but all my children components of that container seem to disappear.

```
Example:
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
          [HostComponent("path.to.skin.MySkinnableContainer")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:states>
         <s:State name="disabled" />
         <s:State name="normal" />
    </s:states>

    <mx:Image source="@Embed('path.to.skin.AllSkinArt.swf#SkinArt')" includeIn="normal"/>

    <!-- SkinParts
    name=contentGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
    name=contentGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
    -->
 </s:Skin>
```

the component that will be skinned, Has an image component that disappears when skinned.

```
<s:SkinnableContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                      width="116" height="74" 
                      addedToStage="onAddedToStage(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        [Bindable]
        private var _screenShot:Bitmap;

        public function updateScreenShot(screenShot:Bitmap):void
        {
            _screenShot = screenShot;

        }

        protected function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
        {
            //do not want the mouse to interact with this object.
            this.mouseEnabled = false;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

 <s:Image
    width="115"
    height="82"
    x="-8"
    y="-109"
    source="{_screenShot}"/>
 </s:SkinnableContainer>
```

Within the CSS document I Have the follwing line of code to set the skin.

```
wd|MySkinnableContainer
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("path.to.MySkinnableContainerSkin");
}
```

In the above example, the Skin works just fine, but the image contained within the SkinnableContainer will disappear.

Comment: You're code sample is very truncated; and I don't think I'm grasping the full extend of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Agree can you post the full code for each part, also you may be excluding some of the parts from your component in the skin if they aren't marked as required skin parts (this is just a guess haven't worked with this much myself yet either) http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/dynamic_skin_parts.html

Comment: I updated to teh full code, hope this helps to clarify my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your skin is missing the `contentGroup` skin part.  It's funny, for a component like `SkinnableContainer`, I would have thought the content group would be required. Alas, it is not.

Add this to your skin:

```
<s:Group id="contentGroup" />
```

And now that the 'contentGroup' skin part exists, the 'SkinnableContainer' should be able to add your child objects to it.

Comment: Sunil Thanks, that was it, I need to add this line of code any time i create a skin?

Comment: You would need to add this anytime you create a skin for a SkinnableContainer.  Each skinnable component has it's own requirements for it's "skin parts".  When you use Flash Builder to create an MXML skin, it will add some comments like this telling you what the skin parts are, and whether or not they are required: `<!-- SkinParts
    name=contentGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
    -->`  Note that it says this part is NOT required, but it's strange b/c the skin seems useless without it :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and ound another way of doing this, I guess the issue is that Image is considered part of the skin. Setting source in skin class made it work for me.

```
<s:SkinnableContainer>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

         [Bindable]
         public var imageSource:String;
         ....................

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
    <s:Image id="sampleImg"/>

</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

The

```
<s:Skin>

    <s:Image id="sampleImg" source="{hostcomponent.imageSource}"/>

</s:Skin>
```